# Kannel vs Jasmin SMS

Tags: sms, kannel, jasmin-sms

I've encountered a choice I have to make.

Please advise what is the best choice for SMS platform between Kannel and Jasmin SMS. Who knows any pros and cons?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a python programmer I feel more comfortable with Jasmin. It works very well, and the main advantage to me is that I can customize anything I need.

My experience with Jasmin is great, and I currently use it to connect to 4 SMSC and load balance between them. I have sent millions of messages without any performance problems at all.

My experience tells me that every SMSC has specific needs, and with Jasmin I can go into the code and change what I need.

This code is well written !

Comment: I am just getting to know the business of bulk sms. I am not very familiar with the whole gateway setup. Can you point me to an article / tutorial that explains how this gateway works. I have been able to setup Jasmin form the documentation but then I am lost as to how I will connect my modem or phone with this gateway and use it with a panel I made with Django?

Comment: @balsagoth Is there web gui for jasmin?

Comment: @balsagoth Do I need to connect a gsm modem with jasim to send sms?

Comment: @Umair no. You need to connect to an smpp server (SMSC). Just search for smpp server providers on Google. There are tons of them.

Comment: @balsagoth Telnet is an smpp server? Can you suggest any opensource?

Comment: @balsagoth I have configured Jasmin as Client-Server. I want to store the all MT data in databse. Can you please help how can I store the data?

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam you have an example on the documentation http://docs.jasminsms.com/en/latest/faq/developers.html#how-to-log-messages-in-a-third-party-database or you can set an `EvalPyFilter`. If you need more help, I suggest opening a new Question.

Comment: Hi, there is a web gui for control the jasmin gw, written in django and python, https://github.com/101t/jasmin-web-panel

Answer (score 1):

Both systems are very versatile and can be configured to perform complex tasks.

2 main difference that i find :

1. SMPP: Kannel implements only smpp client functionality and cannot act as SMPP server , while JasminSMS implements both.
2. MODEM: Modem interaction is very flexible using Kannel. I think its not available in the JasminSMS, but can be added using a plugin (https://github.com/jookies/jasmin/issues/697)